# Conditional query with Grid View asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

> Here I am use asp.net c# and SQL Server 2008.
>   I want to show my record into Grid View with conditional parameter
>   from Text Box, Dropdown List, Date of Birth and range of date. My
>   Design View is bellow:

```
 <div>
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Application ID</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrmCardID" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">Applicant Name</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrmCCAppName" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">Source Code</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPrmCardSourceCode" runat="server" Width="105px">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Date of Birth</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrmDOB" runat="server" Width="100px" ToolTip="DD MMM YYYY"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CECCCLDOB" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="txtPrmDOB" Format="dd MMM yyyy" FirstDayOfWeek="Sunday">
                 </asp:CalendarExtender>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">Card Status</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPrmCardStatus" runat="server" Width="105px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                        DataSourceID="DSCardStatus" DataTextField="CardStatus" 
                        DataValueField="CardStatus">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="%"> -SELECT- </asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSCardStatus" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OptimaWebCustomerQueryCon %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [CardStatusID], [CardStatus] FROM [CC_CardStatus] ORDER BY [CardStatusID]">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">Credit Officer</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPrmCardAssignOfficer" runat="server" Width="105px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                        DataSourceID="DSCreditOfficer" DataTextField="COName" DataValueField="COName">
                       <asp:ListItem Value="%"> -SELECT- </asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSCreditOfficer" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OptimaWebCustomerQueryCon %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [COID], [COName], [COStatus] FROM [DDLCreditOfficerList] WHERE ([COStatus] = @COStatus) ORDER BY [COID]">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Active" Name="COStatus" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Reg No</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrmCardRegNo" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">File No</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrmFileNo" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">Card No</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Received Date From</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrmCardReceivedDateFrom" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="txtPrmCardReceivedDateFrom" Format="dd MMM yyyy" FirstDayOfWeek="Sunday">
                 </asp:CalendarExtender>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">Received Date To</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrmCardReceivedDateTo" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender3" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="txtPrmCardReceivedDateTo" Format="dd MMM yyyy" FirstDayOfWeek="Sunday">
                 </asp:CalendarExtender>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">Request Amount</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrmCardRequestLimit" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Approved Date From</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrmApprovedDatefrom" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="txtPrmApprovedDatefrom" Format="dd MMM yyyy" FirstDayOfWeek="Sunday">
                 </asp:CalendarExtender>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">Approved Date To</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrmApprovedDateTo" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender4" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="txtPrmApprovedDateTo" Format="dd MMM yyyy" FirstDayOfWeek="Sunday">
                 </asp:CalendarExtender>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">Approved Amount</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrmPostApprovedLimit" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnRiskRefresh" runat="server" onclick="btnRiskRefresh_Click" 
                        Text="Refresh" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnRiskQuerySearch" runat="server" 
                        onclick="btnRiskQuerySearch_Click1" Text="Search" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </div>
    <div>
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelRiskQuery" ScrollBars="Both" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GVCardRiskQuery" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CardID" 
            DataSourceID="DSCardRiskQuery" ondatabound="GVCardRiskQuery_DataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CardID" HeaderText="CardID" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="CardID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CCCLName" HeaderText="CCCLName" 
                    SortExpression="CCCLName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CardReceivedDate" HeaderText="CardReceivedDate" 
                    SortExpression="CardReceivedDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CardAssignDate" HeaderText="CardAssignDate" 
                    SortExpression="CardAssignDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CardAssignOfficer" HeaderText="CardAssignOfficer" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CardAssignOfficer" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CardSourceCode" HeaderText="CardSourceCode" 
                    SortExpression="CardSourceCode" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CCCLDOB" HeaderText="CCCLDOB" 
                    SortExpression="CCCLDOB" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CardStatus" HeaderText="CardStatus" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="CardStatus" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CardRequestLimit" HeaderText="CardRequestLimit" 
                    SortExpression="CardRequestLimit" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CardProductGroup" HeaderText="CardProductGroup" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CardProductGroup" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CardEntryDate" HeaderText="CardEntryDate" 
                    SortExpression="CardEntryDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CCCIBSendingDate" HeaderText="CCCIBSendingDate" 
                    SortExpression="CCCIBSendingDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CCCIBReceivedDate" HeaderText="CCCIBReceivedDate" 
                    SortExpression="CCCIBReceivedDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CardCPVSentDate" HeaderText="CardCPVSentDate" 
                    SortExpression="CardCPVSentDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CardCPVRcevDate" HeaderText="CardCPVRcevDate" 
                    SortExpression="CardCPVRcevDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PostApprovedLimit" HeaderText="PostApprovedLimit" 
                    SortExpression="PostApprovedLimit" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PostApprovedDate" HeaderText="PostApprovedDate" 
                    SortExpression="PostApprovedDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PostApprovedCard" HeaderText="PostApprovedCard" 
                    SortExpression="PostApprovedCard" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSCardRiskQuery" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OptimaWebCustomerQueryCon %>"             
            SelectCommand="SELECT [CardID], [CCCLName], [CardReceivedDate], [CardAssignDate], [CardSourceCode],
                            [CardAssignOfficer], CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[CCCLDOB],106) AS CCCLDOB, [CardStatus], [CardRequestLimit], 
                            [CardProductGroup], [CardEntryDate], [CCCIBSendingDate], [CCCIBReceivedDate], 
                            [CardCPVSentDate], [CardCPVRcevDate], [PostApprovedLimit], [PostApprovedDate], 
                            [PostApprovedCard] FROM [Vcard_MasterQuery] 
                            WHERE  CardID LIKE @CardID
                            AND (CCCLName like '%' + @CCCLName OR CCCLName like @CCCLName + '%' OR CCCLName like '%' + @CCCLName + '%')            
                            AND isnull(CardStatus,'') like @CardStatus
                                    AND isnull(CCCLDOB,'') Like @CCCLDOB                         
                                    AND isnull(CardAssignOfficer,'') like @CardAssignOfficer
                                    AND (Convert(varchar,isnull([PostApprovedLimit],0)) like @PostApprovedLimit)  
                                    AND (Convert(varchar,isnull([CardRequestLimit],0)) like @CardRequestLimit)
                                    AND (DATEADD(s,1, isnull([CardReceivedDate],'')) &gt; @CardReceivedDate)  
                                    AND (DATEADD(s,-1,isnull([CardReceivedDate],'')) &lt; @CardReceivedDate2)                                                             
                                    AND (DATEADD(s,1, isnull([PostApprovedDate],'')) &gt; @PostApprovedDate)  
                                    AND (DATEADD(s,-1,isnull([PostApprovedDate],'')) &lt; @PostApprovedDate2)"
        onselecting="DSCardRiskQuery_Selecting">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CardID" />            
            <asp:Parameter Name="CCCLDOB" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CCCLName" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CardRequestLimit" />  
            <asp:Parameter Name="PostApprovedLimit" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CardReceivedDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CardReceivedDate2" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PostApprovedDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PostApprovedDate2" /> 
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDLPrmCardStatus" Name="CardStatus" PropertyName="SelectedValue" /> 
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDLPrmCardAssignOfficer" Name="CardAssignOfficer" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource> 

        </asp:Panel>
    </div>

    protected void DSCardRiskQuery_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPrmCCAppName.Text.Length == 0) e.Command.Parameters["@CCCLName"].Value = "%";
        else e.Command.Parameters["@CCCLName"].Value = txtPrmCCAppName.Text;
        if (txtPrmCardID.Text.Length == 0) e.Command.Parameters["@CardID"].Value = "%";
        else e.Command.Parameters["@CardID"].Value = txtPrmCardID.Text;
        if (txtPrmDOB.Text.Length == 0) e.Command.Parameters["@CCCLDOB"].Value = "%";
        else e.Command.Parameters["@CCCLDOB"].Value = txtPrmDOB.Text;

        if (txtPrmCardReceivedDateFrom.Text.Length == 0) e.Command.Parameters["@CardReceivedDate"].Value = DateTime.Parse("1jan2009");
        else e.Command.Parameters["@CardReceivedDate"].Value = DateTime.Parse(txtPrmCardReceivedDateFrom.Text);
        if (txtPrmCardReceivedDateTo.Text.Length == 0) e.Command.Parameters["@CardReceivedDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
        else e.Command.Parameters["@CardReceivedDate"].Value = DateTime.Parse(txtPrmCardReceivedDateTo.Text);
        if (txtPrmCardRequestLimit.Text.Length == 0) e.Command.Parameters["@CardRequestLimit"].Value = "%";
        else e.Command.Parameters["@CardRequestLimit"].Value = txtPrmCardRequestLimit.Text;
        if (txtPrmPostApprovedLimit.Text.Length == 0) e.Command.Parameters["@PostApprovedLimit"].Value = "%";
        else e.Command.Parameters["@PostApprovedLimit"].Value = txtPrmPostApprovedLimit.Text;
    }
    protected void btnRiskQuerySearch_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DSCardRiskQuery.DataBind();
    }


protected void btnRiskRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtPrmCardID.Text = "";
        txtPrmCCAppName.Text = "";
        DDLPrmCardSourceCode.SelectedValue = "%";
        DDLPrmCardStatus.SelectedValue = "%";
        txtPrmCardRequestLimit.Text = "";
        DDLPrmCardAssignOfficer.SelectedValue = "%";
        txtPrmPostApprovedLimit.Text = "";
        txtPrmCardRegNo.Text = "";
        txtPrmFileNo.Text = "";
        txtPrmCardReceivedDateFrom.Text = "";
        txtPrmCardReceivedDateTo.Text = "";
    }
```

> There are problem that when I load page, Grid View data is not shown. 
>   when I use CCCLName, DDLPrmCardStatus, DDLPrmCardAssignOfficer
>   parameter then grid view recored is shown but parameter is not work.
>   How can I solve this problem

Comment: Make sure that your gridview binding code is inside if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               Bind Grid here
            } in page load. This is where most people make mistake

Comment: Where is condition? can you summarize code?

Comment: Wher I use Sql data source with SelectCommand with parameter. I am not use any !IsPostBack for previous page